# What is the best way of acessing a collection from userform in this case?

Tags: vba, ms-word

So, in my main module I have a collection `food` consisting of dictionaries. Each dictionary has `name` entry and `color` entry. The code populating the collection doesn't matter, but here it is:

```
Option Explicit

Dim food As New Collection

Sub PopulateCollection()

    Dim dict1 As New Scripting.Dictionary
    dict1.Add "name", "apple"
    dict1.Add "color", "red"

    Dim dict2 As New Scripting.Dictionary
    dict2.Add "name", "banana"
    dict2.Add "color", "yellow"

    Dim dict3 As New Scripting.Dictionary
    dict3.Add "name", "cucumber"
    dict3.Add "color", "green"

    food.Add dict1
    food.Add dict2
    food.Add dict3

End Sub
```

I also have a userform `UFTest` with combobox `CBBTest` and the button `ButtonTest` like this:

[image]

**What I need:**

1. Populate the combobox with `name` entries from the collection so it
   has the options: `apple`, `banana`, `cucumber`.
2. Upon picking the food and clicking "show color" button, the userform
   shall return the corresponding color into `debug.print`.

The code in the main module to run the userform:

```
Sub RunUserForm()

    PopulateCollection

    'create an exemplar of the userform
    Dim form1 As New UFTest

    'pass the collection to the sub to populate the combobox
    form1.FillUserform food

    'show the form
    form1.Show
End Sub
```

The `FillUserform` sub of the userform:

```
Option Explicit

Sub FillUserform(Coll As Collection)
    Dim Item As Variant

    'erase previous items just to be sure
    Me.CBBTest.Clear

    'iterate through the collection to add names into the combobox
    For Each Item In Coll
        Me.CBBTest.AddItem Item.Item("name")
    Next Item

    'Make the first item selected
    Me.CBBTest.ListIndex = 0

End Sub
```

So, when `Sub ButtonTest_Click()` is fired, how do I refer back to the collection and invoke the `color` item? I could put all the code initializing the collection into the userform. It works, but it doesn't feel right. I also could declare the `food` collection as public, but people advice against the public variables and BTW the userform can't see it anyway for some reason. What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best way because I do not know why you need a collection of dicitonaries. I would use a simple class instead, for your purposes you might want to  add *setters* and *getters*. I named the class `clsfood`.

```
Option Explicit

Public myName As String
Public mycolor As String
```

I changed the code in the userform like that

```
Option Explicit
Dim coll As Collection
Property Set foodColl(nCol As Collection)
    Set coll = nCol
End Property

Sub FillUserform() '(coll As Collection)
    Dim Item As Variant

    'erase previous items just to be sure
    Me.CBBTest.Clear

    'iterate through the collection to add names into the combobox
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To coll.Count
        Me.CBBTest.AddItem coll.Item(i).myName
    Next

    'Make the first item selected
    Me.CBBTest.ListIndex = 0

End Sub

Private Sub btnShowColor_Click()
    Debug.Print CBBTest.Value, CBBTest.ListIndex; coll.Item(CBBTest.ListIndex + 1).mycolor
End Sub
```

And that is the code in the module

```
Option Explicit

Dim colFood As New Collection

Sub PopulateCollection()

    Dim food As clsFood

    Set food = New clsFood
    food.myName = "apple"
    food.mycolor = "red"
    colFood.Add food

    Set food = New clsFood
    food.myName = "banana"
    food.mycolor = "yellow"
    colFood.Add food

    Set food = New clsFood
    food.myName = "cucumber"
    food.mycolor = "green"
    colFood.Add food

End Sub
Sub RunUserForm()

    PopulateCollection

    'create an exemplar of the userform
    Dim form1 As New UFTest

    With form1

        'pass the collection to the sub to populate the combobox
        Set .foodColl = colFood
        .FillUserform

        'show the form
        .Show
    End With

End Sub
```

**Update**: As a class is not the way you want/can follow I just changed your code like that

Code in the module

```
Option Explicit

Dim food As New Collection

Sub PopulateCollection()

    Dim dict1 As New Scripting.Dictionary
    dict1.Add "name", "apple"
    dict1.Add "color", "red"

    Dim dict2 As New Scripting.Dictionary
    dict2.Add "name", "banana"
    dict2.Add "color", "yellow"

    Dim dict3 As New Scripting.Dictionary
    dict3.Add "name", "cucumber"
    dict3.Add "color", "green"

    food.Add dict1
    food.Add dict2
    food.Add dict3

End Sub
Sub RunUserForm()

    PopulateCollection

    'create an exemplar of the userform
    Dim form1 As New UFTest

    With form1

        'pass the collection to the sub to populate the combobox
        Set .foodColl = food
        .FillUserform

        'show the form
        .Show
    End With

End Sub
```

Code in the Userform

```
Option Explicit
Dim coll As Collection
Property Set foodColl(nCol As Collection)
    Set coll = nCol
End Property

Sub FillUserform() '(coll As Collection)
    Dim Item As Variant

    'erase previous items just to be sure
    Me.CBBTest.Clear

    'iterate through the collection to add names into the combobox
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To coll.Count
        Me.CBBTest.AddItem coll.Item(i).Item("name")
    Next

    'Make the first item selected
    Me.CBBTest.ListIndex = 0

End Sub

Private Sub btnShowColor_Click()
    Debug.Print CBBTest.Value, CBBTest.ListIndex, coll.Item(CBBTest.ListIndex + 1).Item("color")
End Sub
```

Comment: I used collection because I need many key-value pairs created dynamically from excel data. AFAIK you can't do it with classes. I did not mention it because my answer is lenghty enough already, sorry.

Comment: But this should give you anyway a hint how to access the dictionary in the collection, right?

Comment: I declared the public collection within the userform and populated it from "outside" and it works. Not sure if I can realise more secure approach with collections. I guess it answers my question then.

Comment: You could also just return the index of the selected entry.

Comment: Excuse me, but how can I return it (to the main module I assume) if it's initiated by a `_click` event within the form?

Comment: You could hide the form, do whatever you want to do in the main module and return to the form again. But as I do not really know what are your requirements are it's probably best to pass the collection to the form.